# Expectation of Indicator Functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \,\, ... \,\, , X_6$ all be indicator functions that are **independent of each other**. Each indicator is 'activated' with probability *p* and not active with probability $(1 - p)$.

Determine the probability $P(\xi = 1)$ where  $\xi$ is as follows:

$$\xi = 1 - \{(1-X_5)(1 - X_1X_2)(1 - X_4X_3)(1 - X_1X_6X_3)(1-X_4X_6X_2)\}$$

**Attempted Solution**:

I understand the following:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1] = 1*p + 0*(1 - p) = p = P(X_1 = 1) = p$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] = \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]$$
due to independence.

Applying this to $\xi$ is the following valid?
$$\mathbb{E}[\xi] = \mathbb{E}[1] - \{\mathbb{E}[(1-X_5)]\mathbb{E}[(1 - X_1X_2)] \\\mathbb{E}[(1 - X_4X_3)]\mathbb{E}[(1 - X_1X_6X_3)]\mathbb{E}[(1-X_4X_6X_2)]\}$$
which can be further distributed as:
$$\mathbb{E}[\xi] = 1 - \{(1-\mathbb{E}[X_5])(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]) \\(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_4X_3])(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_1X_6X_3])(1-\mathbb{E}[X_4X_6X_2])\}$$
and by applying the above properties:
$$\mathbb{E}[\xi] = 1 - \{(1-\mathbb{E}[X_5])(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]) \\(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_4]\mathbb{E}[X_3])(1 - \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_6]\mathbb{E}[X_3])(1-\mathbb{E}[X_4]\mathbb{E}[X_6]\mathbb{E}[X_2])\}$$
which just ends up being:
$$P(\xi = 1) = \mathbb{E}[\xi] = 1 - \{(1-p)(1 - p^2) \\(1 - p^2)(1 - p^3)(1-p^3)\}$$

My concern here is that I basically replaced the indicator functions in $\xi$ with the corresponding activated probability $p$ when looking for $P(\xi = 1)$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not all of the factors in the second term are independent. For instance $1-X_1X_2$ and $1-X_1X_6X_3$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work; for instance, as @drhab noted, the factors $(1 - X_1 X_2)$ and $(1 - X_1 X_6 X_3)$ are not independent, since they both include the term $X_1$.

Instead, consider the following approach:

1. The very first factor of $(1 - X_5)$ is genuinely independent of the rest, since $X_5$ uniquely appears in that term. We can peel off that part of the expectation, i.e. 
   $$\mathbb E[(1 - X_5) (1 - X_1 X_2) \cdots] = \mathbb E[1 - X_5] \cdot \mathbb E[(1 - X_1 X_2) \cdots]$$
2. The second term consists of four factors that are hopelessly entangled due to the repeated variables. But, you can fix this with algebra: note that indicator variables have the nice property that $X_i^2 = X_i$, since $1^2 = 1$ and $0^2 = 0$. Use that property to expand the term on the right, and then use the linearity of expectation and independence of the individual $X_i$ terms to proceed.